# Mapping large XML documents using JAXB or Alternative

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, mapping

I am trying to map large XML documents specified by a large set of XSDs to another large XML document (About 2500 lines). The mapping is not exactly one to one, but it's relatively close, with maybe 30-40 elements changing, some needing to be concatenated, or basic filtering logic performed on them. I've found Altova MapForce to be a good solution, however it seems to be overkill as far as the features it provides. Another option I've explored is building a custom mapping framework using JAXB, but I fear I would be building a product like MapForce, and I estimate it would take a few hundred man hours.

I have found very little online about XML Mapping, with the biggest finds being a handful of commercial product solutions, all of which seem a bit overkill.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at doing the mapping using [XSL transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)?

Comment: I have with MapForce. It will generate an XSLT document. The downside is it's about 16,000 lines. That would be a bit cumbersome to write manually, and to edit as things change.

Answer (score 0):

I you are using Eclipse IDE, you have an option similar to  File - New - "Create bean from XSD schema". It's very useful!